# Update approval status for copied component

Tags: experience-manager, content-manager, workflow

If editors use the New Page functionality in XPM, which copies page and components, is it possible set the component Approval Status to "Unapproved" or a status that doesn't meet the Minimum Approval Status?

I looked in the Event System but the CopyEventArgs doesn't give you the ApprovalStatusResetOverride SaveEventArgs does.

I could programmatically start a WF in CopyEventArgs that had a single automatic activity to set a "Draft" status but would this apply to the v1.0 of the copied component or create a new version and therefore leave a previous version as "Undefined" that could be rolled back to?

Comment: if it could - perhaps your code could also delete the previous version if v1.0 and undefined ... of course, if you use _force workflow on items created from this schema_ this is likely a lot more problematic :)

Comment: Would that be for the Approval Status for the Target used by XPM? I'm sure it's possible, but I believe the New Page feature will attempt to publish the new items to that Target (so users could see the new page immediately). Having a "lower" status might interfere with seeing the page, right?

Comment: What we want is for content to be publishable to staging (for XPM) but not to live. This seems to be the case with in the CM with enforced bundle workflow - when you create a new component as its greyed out until approved. But New Page in XPM is copying not creating.

Comment: Thinking about, if New Page in XPM is copying then I wonder if I created new templates now bundle workflow is being enforced and used those as a page type would it copy the unapproved 0.1 versions?

Comment: That didnt work - I assume because the New Page process couldn't take ownership of the v0.1 component I'd created on the template

Comment: I guess I might need to tackle this another way - via event system perhaps to prevent a the page created by New Page in XPM, which happens to be at v2 from being published until its v3.

Answer (score 1):

So I went with sending current components used as XPM prototypes through a small WF to get them to Draft.

When New Page is used in XPM this status is copied into the new component, preventing it from begin published (via minimum approval status) when initial created.